# Gazebo outdoor terrain, best way to build from scratch

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-worlds

I want to build an urban outdoor world containing a house, backyard, a street and a few other objects. I've seen some people using a heightmap as grayscale, others use blender to build the terrain. But all these examples I've found are more than 10 years old now.

Is it still the right way to do? Should I use blender for example?

Main concerns are:

- should I add all objects already in blender or should I build terrain only and add houses later in .world file?
- If I add all objects into blender, will this result in a valid collision mesh?
- how to deal with different physics and frictions? I.e. gras should be more slippy than asphalt, a pathway is build with different material and might be somewhat of humpy

Most tutorials I've found either are way too simple, ending with 4 blocks in an empty world. Or they build large scale terrain models of an entire canyon.

I know my question is subjective but it would help if someone share their workflow or send me a good tutorial about this.

BR Patrick